# Assign observations into classes using Sturges rule

Tags: histograms

I have a list of 562 observations that I would like to assign to classes (bins) using Sturges rule.

What is the best way to implement this in Mathematica?

Comment: `Histogram[data, "Sturges"]`

Comment: or `HistogramList[data, "Sturges"]`